# Obtain a file id from a file name using a regex

Tags: java, regex, expression

How would I obtain the file id from the following filename strings using a regular expression.

Example list:

file1.doc
file2.doc
file3.doc...

Desired result:
1
2
3

I have tried:

```
^[^file] [0-9]+ [^\.doc]$
```

But had no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following regex to get it:

```
^file(\d+)\.doc$
```

You seem to be misusing `[]` - it means "any character that is inside brackets" and `[^]` means "any character **but** those in the brackets". You need neither of them here.